# How to determine buffer size for vswprintf under Linux gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, unicode

I need to allocate a sufficient buffer for format function vswprintf(). When doing the same thing with ANSI string, I'm using:

```
vsnprintf( NULL, NULL, pszFormat, args );
```

which returns me required size of a buffer. But it seems that unicode version of this function doesn't have this functionality. When I execute:

```
vswprintf( NULL, NULL, pszFormat, args );
```

result value is always -1.

Only solution which I found is using a large static buffer for calculation required size. But I don't like this solution:

```
static const int nBuffSize = 1024;
static XCHAR evalBuff[nBuffSize];
int nSize = vswprintf( evalBuff, nBuffSize, pszFormat, args );
if ( nSize != -1 )
{
 return nSize;
}
else
{
 throw XXX;
}
```

Is there any way how to measure required buffer size for unicode strings?

Regards
Ludek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opening a dummy file to /dev/null (or NUL under windows) and printing to that file to retrieve the size works very well (it is faster than printing to a string):

#if !defined(_MSC_VER) 
      printf_dummy_file = fopen("/dev/null", "wb"); 
  #else 
      printf_dummy_file = fopen("NUL", "wb"); 
  #endif

...

n = vfprintf(printf_dummy_file, format, args);

The "fopen" part should be done once (you can use a static variable, or the constructor of a global variable if you are using C++).

Comment: `vfwprintf` rather than `vfprintf`, but +1 anyway. And remember to use a copy of the va_list.

Comment: Thank you for this tip. Only drawback of this solution is 5x slower than original function vswprintf. So I will use this function for *nix systems, but original function for Win system. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A bit heavyweight, but if nobody comes up with anything better you could exponentially grow a buffer until it's big enough:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> vec(512);
int nSize;
do {
    vec.resize(vec.size()*2);
    va_list args2;
    va_copy args2, args;
    nSize = vswprintf(&vec[0], vec.size(), format, args2);
    va_end args2
} while(nSize < 0);
// now I have the length, and the formatted string to copy if required.
```

Since you're on POSIX, you'd think that an errno would be defined for insufficient buffer space, and that this errno should be checked in the `while` condition, so that other errors don't cause a resource-hungry loop. But there's no such errno defined at http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fwprintf.html, so I guess you'll have to test what errno you actually get on your implementation (if any).

Another option is to get rid of the format strings, and instead write to a `wostringstream`. But that's not much use if your format string needs to be configured after compile-time.

Comment: Thank you for this tip, but it's much more time consuming than solution suggested by John Rusta, so I decide for his way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a C++ only solution:
[libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt#readme) has its own sprintf implementation, applicable to both `std::string` and `std::wstring`.
Ex :

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/printf.h>

std::wstring ws = fmt::sprintf(L"The answer is %d.", 42);
```

Answer (score -2):

This will get the buffer size:

vswprintf(nullptr, -1, pszFormat, args);

Comment: @Programmdude: It will return -1 for all of you, that happened to have a `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code (or `using std::vswprintf`). For everyone else it will return the required buffer size (or a compiler error).

Comment: @IInspectable your comment is wrong, C++ delegates to the C spec for `vswprintf` without specifying any changes in behaviour ; and the C spec says that `vswprintf` makes it undefined behaviour to pass null pointer as first argument