# pre-calculating string length for va_list versions of _snprintf / _snwprintf

Tags: c++, string

Is there a va_list style version of the following code to safely do a non-truncated sprintf:

```
// format a char buffer
int size = 1 + _snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", 132);
std::vector<char> buffer (size);
sprintf_s(&buffer[0], buffer.size (), "%d", 132);

// format a wchar_t buffer
int wsize = 1 + _snwprintf(NULL, 0, L"%d", 132);
std::vector<wchar_t> wbuffer (wsize);
swprintf_s(&wbuffer[0], wbuffer.size (), L"%d", 132);
```

As far as I can tell from the documentation and experimentation, all the _vsnprintf functions do not return a calculation of the length, and only truncate or generate an error. Is there an alternative?

Comment: This is using Microsoft's compiler and runtime, I take it? The ANSI standard vsprintf and related functions all have the "correct" behaviour of returning what the length would have been without truncation. (Not that that's much consolation to you, of course!)

Comment: Yes, that's right, Microsoft compiler.

Comment: I'm not a C programmer, but I think the ANSI C `vsprintf` function returns the number of characters that were actually stored in the buffer, not the number that would have been stored without truncation.

Comment: If this is supposed to be C++, have you considered using std::stringstream?

Comment: Yes, I've looked at stringstream. It is of course possible, but like all the streamed I/O it's awkward to use especially with format specifiers.

Comment: Looking at the ANSI version of this now. It seems that whike vsnsprintf is OK for narrow strings, vswprintf does not do what is needed for wide strings. It returns 0.

Comment: This answers it for wide strings on linux, though it's a total hack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107947/how-to-determine-buffer-size-for-vswprintf-under-linux-gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio provides the `_vscprintf` function to check the amount of buffer needed to store the resulting string.