# How to format wide char string via vswprintf on OSX (want to return std::wstring)

Tags: c++, windows, macos, c++11

I need implement a function to format wide char string and return std::wstring. My implementation is:

```
std::wstring format(const wchar_t* fmt, ...)
{
    std::wstring ret;

    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);

    int size = vswprintf(nullptr, 0, fmt, va);
    if (size > 0)
    {
        ret.resize(size + 1);
        vswprintf(&ret[0], size + 1, fmt, va);
    }

    va_end(va);
    return ret;
}
```

it works well on windows, but unfortunately it doesn't work on osx because vswprintf(nullptr, 0, fmt, va) will return -1.

only std can be used and I can't assume the string length is in a certain range.

I think there should be some way to do that, but I can't find, can you help? thanks

Comment: Can you try to give a legit pointer, instead of `nullptr`? maybe there is extra check of pointer validity.

Comment: @SHR not work, return -1

Comment: What you observe (on OS X) is documented behavior for [std::vswprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfwprintf) (*"Return value [is a] negative value if [...] the number of characters to be generated was equal or greater than size."*). You have to keep looping, reading into a local buffer, until that buffer is large enough to hold the final formatted string, and return a `std::wstring` over that buffer. Unfortunately, there is no standard implementation of Microsoft's [_vscwprintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w05tbk72.aspx) extension.

Comment: This talks about Linux, but the question is basically the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107947/how-to-determine-buffer-size-for-vswprintf-under-linux-gcc

Comment: @IInspectable what I read is http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfwprintf, If bufsz is zero, nothing is written (and buffer may be a null pointer), however the return value (number of wide characters that would be written) is still calculated and returned.    Amazing! they are different

Comment: @P.X: I didn't know that there was a difference between C and C++ either. In that case, the most pragmatic solution would be to move the call `vswprintf(nullptr, 0, fmt, va)` into its own function in a separate translation unit, compile it as "C", and link against it from your C++ code. That way you get the required buffer size without workarounds, in a platform-independent way (except for the build environment/system). Alternatively, use the C implementation in the global namespace by prepending `::`, i.e. `::vswprintf( ... )`.

Comment: @P.X There is no difference, the information in point 3 near the top of that page is wrong. If you scroll down to the "return value" section it gives the correct info. Of course you can always read the C standard.

Comment: Maybe, I see vswprintf in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf  it says nothing about what that will be if the buffer is nullptr.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Darwin version is actually behaving
[according to the specification for `vfwprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfwprintf). Unfortunately, it also seems there is no convenient way to calculate the length of a *wide* formatted string in the same way you would a regular single byte string (by passing a `NULL` destination string).

After much researching, I have found there seem to be two viable solutions, both of which are mentioned in this answer:

- [How to determine buffer size for vswprintf under Linux gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107947/how-to-determine-buffer-size-for-vswprintf-under-linux-gcc)

I dislike the iterative allocation approach as it seems inefficient to blindly attempt the same operation many times until you have allocated enough.

My preferred solution is to format the string (once!) to `/dev/null` first in order to calculate the length, and then use this to size your buffer. It is necessary to copy the variable args list to do this, as it is consumed by the vs*functions.  This is closest to how you were doing it anyway, just with a null stream instead of a null string.

My proposed solution is thus:

```
std::wstring format(const wchar_t* fmt, ...)
{
    std::wstring ret;

    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);

    va_list vc;
    va_copy(vc, va);

    FILE* fp = fopen("/dev/null", "w");
    int size = vfwprintf(fp, fmt, vc);
    fclose(fp);

    if (size > 0)
    {
        ret.resize(size + 1);
        vswprintf(&ret[0], size + 1, fmt, va);
    }

    va_end(va);
    va_end(vc);

    return ret;
}
```

I tested this on Mac OS X with the following code, and observed the expected output:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto outstr = format(L"Hello %ls, you are %u years old.\n", L"Fred", 65);

    std::wcout << outstr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @IInspectable only insofaras OP code is undefined behaviour, so all compilers are compliant...

Comment: The `/dev/null/` solution is non-portable, obviously

Comment: @M.M For Windows, using `NUL` instead of `/dev/null` should work just fine. Confirmed by poster in the linked thread above.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
buffer.resize(1)
loop:
    res = vswprintf(buffer, args)
    if res indicates success:
        break
    buffer.resize(buffer.size() * 2)
buffer.truncate()
```

In other words, you simply try with increasing buffer sizes until you succeed. I'd start off with something larger than 1 char though, basically so that most calls don't have to be repeated, but that's just performance finetuning.

Comment: thank you, I have considered this way, but it's possible to be an endless loop since vswprintf could fail for some other reason

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure even after studying the Linux manpage intensely whether truncation is considered an error or not. If it isn't, the returnvalue would allow you to distinguish between success (break), error (throw) and truncation (repeat).

Comment: `buffer.truncate()` is not at all required. `vswprintf` already provided the valid range through its return value. Growing the buffer exponentially is usually not a good option either. Grow it linearly instead.

Comment: Truncating the buffer is necessary to remove the trailing characters in the buffer that were not used (due to overallocation) but which are still part of it. Of course, you need the returnvalue of `vswprintf()` to determine this exact size. Why would you advise against exponential buffer resizing, @IInspectable?

Comment: [std::wstring](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) has a constructor taking an explicit length parameter, so the excess space of the local buffer doesn't matter. Exponential buffer growth has 2 drawbacks: It will fail more often than linear buffer growth, and it will - on average - waste more memory than linear growth.

Comment: The local buffer **is** perhaps an `std::wstring`, so it can be returned without having to copy the data once more. However, before returning it, I need to truncate it to the correct size then. In any case, constructing a `std::wstring` with a pointer/size pair for returning is equivalent to truncating, especially when used in pseudocode. Point remains, since you overallocate, you have to truncate to correct size.

Comment: Concerning your assertions about the growth, using exponential growth you will find a suitable size after fewer attempts (thus formatting fails less often) but also run out of memory after fewer attempts (thus reallocation fails more often). Without precise definition of the goals of the function (I'm also just assuming the use case is similar to what I have experienced in the past) any discussion about performance tuning is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be to use the C11 standard function `vswprintf_s` function.  This is not fully portable because C11 makes it optional for this function to be implemented, but I mention it in case your implementation does implement it.

C++14 only specifies the C99 standard library, and this function is in C11. But if your C++ compiler's associated C compiler supports C11 then it is likely to make the function directly available from C++. Even if it doesn't, you could wrap that code in a C function and call that C function from C++.

The `vswprintf_s` function uses different arguments to `vswprintf` so check its documentation carefully.

Comment: thank you. btw, I can't see any arguments difference between vswprintf and vswprintf_s, from http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfwprintf, what did you mean?